# Does StringBuilder in .net 4.5 have chunks larger than MaxChunkSize

Tags: append, stringbuilder, chunks, large-object-heap

In .net 4.5 CLR team has change `StringBuilder` class a lot. [Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs#a0883e34542ee453#references) is the code reference for `StringBuilder` class. Here we can find `MaxChunkSize` equal to 8000 and comment above this field:

```
// We want to keep chunk arrays out of large object heap (< 85K bytes ~ 40K chars) to be sure.
// Making the maximum chunk size big means less allocation code called, but also more waste
// in unused characters and slower inserts / replaces (since you do need to slide characters over
// within a buffer).
```

So I still wonder, if we would work with `StringBuilder` appending large string, e.g. :

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(<<Here comes the string with length larger than 80 000 symbols>>);
```

Would we still have ChunksArrays allocated in LargeObjectHeap?

Answer (score 0):

My instincts say that you'd still get tagged by the LOH for the big string itself; if your string is bigger than the limit, it'll still live in the LOH, although the `StringBuilder` would not.

Let's test that out:

```
void Main()
{
    var big_ass_string = new String('a', 80001);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(big_ass_string);
    var generation_of_builder = GC.GetGeneration(sb);
    var generation_of_string = GC.GetGeneration(big_ass_string);
    Console.WriteLine("StringBuilder is in gen:{0}", generation_of_builder);
    Console.WriteLine("String is in gen:{0}", generation_of_string);
}
```

Output:

```
StringBuilder is in gen:0
String is in gen:2
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is YES (even in .NET 4.5 or higher): each time you call `sb.Append(...some string larger than 40K chars...);` StringBuilder will allocate on Large Object Heap. (Hence, defeating the purpose of the "new" design of StringBuilder.) I posted more detailed info and a possible fix for it here:
https://github.com/amikunov/Large-Object-Heap-Fix-For-.NET-String-Builder